# Error occurred during initialization of VM when doing grails -version

Tags: linux, jvm, heap-memory, grails-2.0

I am trying to upgrade Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.0.3 in Linux. And I am getting the message as follows:
**Error occurred during initialization of VM** when typing the command **grails -version**

This is what I did

1. wget http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-2.0.3.zip
2. unzip grails-2.0.3.zip
3. mv grails-2.0.3 /usr/share
4. in /etc/profile GRAILS_HOME=/usr/share/grails-2.0.3 followed by export GRAILS_HOME, followed by addition to PATH env variable.
5. Closed the session
6. Restarted the session. Typed grails -version
7. **Error occurred during initialization of VM
   Could not reserve enough space for object heap**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by creating a **GRAILS_OPTS** environment variable as follows and added it to the **/etc/profile**:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-server -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```